# How to convert SQL query to noSQL-query (MongoDB)?

Tags: sql, database, mongodb

Here is the SQL-query:

```
UPDATE users
SET balance = (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM payments WHERE to_id = 1)
WHERE id = 1
```

How can it be converted to MongoDB one-query?
More general question: whats the optimal way of writing multi-update queries in MongoDB?

Comment: Bulk write for unrelated multiple updates or updateMany for same condition logic based updates.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `db.collection.updateMany()` is what you are looking for.

You can find more information in the documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/

Comment: This cannot be an answer. Can you please show me an example of the query from my question written in mongodb with updateMany?